# im having trouble launching an already made program with a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to launch scp containment breach with a batch file, it opens the cmd.exe but won't launch the game here's what I have (I am a beginner)

Batch file code is as follows:

```
@echo off
REM Next command opens SCP - Containment Breach v0.7.4 
start /d "C:\SCP - Containment Breach v0.7.4\"
start "C:\SCP - Containment Breach v0.7.4\"
```

Comment: I'd bet, it works better, if you try to start a program, not a path...

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure whether this will work for your situation since you didn't give very much information, but give this a try.

```
@echo off
cd C:\SCP - Containment Breach v0.7.4\
start SCP - Containment Breach v0.7.4.exe
```

Comment: This won't work.  The .exe name has spaces in it, so it will need to be quoted.  Otherwise it assumes you're trying to start a program called `SCP` with 4 parameters.

The `cd` command works because it takes all arguments after it as a single directory name.

Comment: Hmm, yeah. You're right I suppose. If you quote it though, then you'll get a new command prompt window with the text as a title...

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here.  First, if `start` is passed a quoted string, it treats that as the title of the window it opens, so you're opening a cmd.exe instance with a window title of `C:\SCP - Containment Breach v0.7.4\`.

If you're just trying to start a program, you can just pass that along by itself, without the need for `start`.

```
"C:\SCP - Containment Breach v0.7.4\scp.exe"
```

This assumes that the executable to start is called `scp.exe` so you'll need to change that bit if it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: My quoting last time was a failure. Here is a better one:

I don't know if the thing you're trying to open is a .exe file or a folder, but here you go:

OPEN FOLDER

```
@echo off
REM Next command opens SCP - Containment Breach v0.7.4 
start "" "C:\SCP - Containment Breach v0.7.4\"
```

OPEN EXECUTABLE

```
@echo off
REM Next command opens SCP - Containment Breach v0.7.4 
start "" "C:\SCP - Containment Breach v0.7.4\executable.exe"
```

Comment: its a .exe file inside a folder thats in a folder the path is c:/users/desktop/SCP - Containment Breach v0.7.4-1/SCP - containment Breach v0.7.4.exe